# How to make crontab email me with output?

Tags: email, cron, postfix

How can I make crontab email me with the output of its jobs? I have `MAILTO=redacted@yahoo.com.au` above the jobs, but it doesn't work.

I know I need to use something like Postfix or Sendmail but for the life of me I cannot find out how to achieve this. I've searched and searched for a simple guide on setting up Postfix but they're all insanely complicated and expect you to be setting up a whole server to send and receive email and to know all the terms (like, what is a domain name for outgoing emails?).

All I want to do is have crontab email me. Why is this so difficult??

**Additional Info:**

My crontab file looks like this:

```
MAILTO=redacted@yahoo.com.au
1 0 * * * ~/Desktop/toskymesh.sh
59 6 * * * ~/Desktop/tooptus.sh
0 3 * * * snapraid sync
```

**More Additional Info:**

The output of `ps -ef | grep '[s]endmail'`

```
root 6840 1370 0 10:26 ? 00:00:00 sendmail: MTA: accepting connections
```

I know for sure cron is working, but I'm testing the mail command with `echo Test | mail -s Test redacted@yahoo.com.au` anyway.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In the end I used `sSMTP`. It's far simpler than either `Postfix` or `sendmail` and does the job beautifully.

For future reference, here's how to use sSMTP with Yahoo Mail (don't worry, it's a lot less complex than it looks):

- Use your package manager to download ssmtp. I used Synaptic, but `sudo apt-get install ssmtp` should work as well.
- Open the config file at `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`.
- Make the config look like this:

  ```
  root=yourRealEmail@yahoo.com.au       <--- Use your real email here
  mailhub=smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587       <--- This will depend on your email provider
  FromLineOverride=YES
  UseSTARTTLS=YES
  AuthUser=yourRealEmail@yahoo.com.au   <--- Use your real email here
  AuthPass=yourRealYahooPassword        <--- Use your real email password here
  TLS_CA_File=~/cert.pem
  ```
- Create the cert.pem file with OpenSSL. I used `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 9999 -nodes` (more info at [How to create a self-signed certificate with OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-build-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl)). You can stick the file anywhere, but I just chucked it in ~/. Wherever you put it, make sure you point the `TLS_CA_File=` line in ssmtp.conf to the correct location.
- Open the file `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` and add the line (replacing the appropriate sections with your details):

  ```
  yourPCUsername:yourRealEmail@yahoo.com.au:smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587
  ```

  If you're running as root, I assume you would need to add another line replacing your name with 'root'.
- That's it, you're good to go! To test, the easiest way (IMO) is to create a file with the following in it:

  ```
  To: yourRealEmail@yahoo.com.au                       <--- Use your real email here...
  From: "whateverYaWant" <yourRealEmail@yahoo.com.au>  <--- ...and here
  Subject: Some Notifying Email
  MIME-Version: 1.0
  Content-Type: text/plain

  Body of your email goes here. Hello world!
  ```
- Check that you don't have the real *sendmail* installed by running `sendmail -V`. It should say 'sSMTP'.
- Finally, run `cat fileWithEmailInIt.txt | sendmail -i -t`, then wait a few seconds (10-30) and check your email!

**Additional note 1:** If you have trouble with Gmail, try option 1 of [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/672182).
(Thanks to [Ben Creasy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536766/how-to-make-crontab-email-me-with-output/536934?noredirect=1#comment1325478_536934)!)

**Additional note 2:** If mail is sending from the command line but not through crontab, try changing `FromLineOverride` to `NO` in `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`. You can also get more detailed logging by adding `Debug=YES` to `ssmtp.conf` - the extra logging goes to `/var/log/mail.log`.
(Thanks [Jakub Kukul](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536766/how-to-make-crontab-email-me-with-output/536934?noredirect=1#comment2130777_536934)!)

Comment: What is the point of the .pem file? I see this tutorial doesn't include one: http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-ssmtp.html

Comment: @Richard If I remember correctly, Yahoo Mail refused to receive the email without it, but I'm not 100% sure. You could try it without it first, and if it doesn't work just add the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the sSMTP suggestion.The Ubuntu Wiki has a [helpful guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EmailAlerts) (but don't use an email address for `hostname` as currently shown). [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/800361/184420) suggests that you can use default server certificates, but I found I did not need a `TLS_CA_File=` line for sending via GMail.

Comment: @MarkBerry Indeed, I found lots of information when I was struggling with this, but the problem was that it was _all_ separated and not one single guide covered everything that needed to happen. I suspect it was made more difficult by Yahoo requiring the certificate, but iirc I also tried with a gmail account and couldn't succeed either.

Comment: The Arch linux wiki page for `sSMTP` says it's deprecated. Use `mSMTP` instead

Comment: @MattM. Not deprecated, just not maintained. It should be totally fine to use sSMTP in a non-production environment :)

Comment: Although I can send mail through commandline with this, no mail is sending through crontab... are there other steps missing?

Comment: @E.S. What command did you put in your crontab?

Comment: I had the same problem as @E.S. today - sending mail via commandline worked fine, but no mail was sent through crontab. I fixed it by changing `FromLineOverride` to `NO` in `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`. During debugging, it was also helpful to add `Debug=YES` to `ssmtp.conf` - it resulted in more detailed information being logged to `/var/log/mail.log`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution of using ssmtp, and thanks @JakubKukul, your comment fixed my issue about cannot sending email in crontab.

Answer (score 23):

Install Postfix. It is more complicated than most other packages but it's still not *complicated*.

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Select "Internet Site" and then accept all the defaults. Then we just need to stop outside connections, turning this into a "[null client](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client)". Run: `sudoedit /etc/postfix/main.cf` and find the `inet_interfaces` setting (near the end) and change it to `loopback-only`, like so:

```
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
```

And finally restart Postfix with `sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart` (reloading won't do).

You now have a Postfix install that won't relay email for outside machines, it'll just accept connections on 127.0.0.1 (and ::1 for IPv6).

---

On a separate note, your cron lines are probably not working because you're using non-relative paths and paths with Bash substitutions in. `sh` doesn't understand `~` and it might not have a proper `PATH` set. So replace them with (I'm just guessing at the actual paths):

```
1 0 * * *   /home/clonkex/Desktop/toskymesh.sh
59 6 * * *  /home/clonkex/Desktop/tooptus.sh
0 3 * * *   /usr/bin/snapraid sync
```

And if your scripts require to be run from a specific directory, make sure they `cd` into the right directory. Don't assume that `cron` will be in the right place as it likely won't.

Comment: Thanks, but Postfix *is* complicated, if only because there seem to be no simple guides whatsoever. Anyway, I got it working just fine with sSMTP which does exactly what I need and is genuinely simple (although it still took a lot of fiddling and random guessing to get it to actually work). I meant to post an answer but forgot - I actually managed to [destroy my OS installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/536838/i-purged-tzdata-and-now-lubuntu-wont-boot-help) so as soon as I've got it going again fully I'll post my own answer :)

Comment: And actually my cron jobs worked just fine with `~/Desktop/`.

Comment: I needed `inet_interfaces = localhost`. loopback-only gave me `postfix: fatal: config variable inet_interfaces: host not found: loopback-only`

Answer (score 5):

I had very good luck with exim4.

```
sudo apt-get install alpine exim4 mailutils eximon4 spf-tools-perl swaks
```

(alpine is just the mail client I like using)

After that, I ran

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

and followed through the prompts.  This page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Exim4 was very helpful as well.  It took me about 10 minutes to get it running.

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't want email notifications, but want to log cron jobs' output somewhere to be able to inspect it if need be:

```
# apt install postfix
```

Select "Local only" when asked for a mail server configuration type.

To confirm that `cron` will be able to send mail:

```
# apt install mailutils
# echo test body | mail -s 'test subject' root
# cat /var/mail/root
```

Alternatively add a `cron` job:

```
* * * * * date
```

Wait for it to run (`journalctl -ef` or `watch date`), then `cat /var/mail/root`.

Answer (score 2):

From sSMTP manpage: **"It  does not do aliasing, which must be done either in the user agent or on the mailhub. Nor does it honor .forwards, which have to be done on the recieving host.  It especially does not deliver to pipelines."**

So, if you want to receive all msgs sent to root on your extenal email, it's a bad idea to use sSMTP, because it does not support aliases.

Instead, you could user postfix. It's still very simple. Here's how to use it with gmail as your smtp for sending messages:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix mailutils
```

General type of mail configuration: **Satellite system**

System mail name: The preferred fully-qualified name of the mail server, e.g., **mail.example.com**

SMTP relay host (blank for none): **[smtp.gmail.com]:587**

Add to /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

Create /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 emailtouseforsending@gmail.com:password
```

Then:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
sudo chown -R root:postfix /etc/postfix/sasl
sudo chmod 750 /etc/postfix/sasl
sudo chmod 640 /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd*
```

Edit /etc/aliases and add:

```
root: email@example.com
```

Lastly, run:

```
sudo newaliases
sudo systemctl stop postfix.service
sudo systemctl start postfix.service
```

Now, you can test if redirecting is working:

```
echo "Test to root." | mail -s "Test message to root" root
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I used a pretty simple method to get `cron` to send emails: [Backup Linux configuration, scripts and documents to Gmail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917562/backup-linux-configuration-scripts-and-documents-to-gmail/922493#922493).

### Simplest way to automate sending email

From [Send email alerts using ssmtp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EmailAlerts) we find the simplest way of sending email automated from terminal or script. The installation steps are straight forward:

```
sudo apt install ssmtp
sudo nano /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
# Change "MyEmailAddress" and "MyPassword" to your own.
```

There  is one step not mentioned; Google will send you an email confirming you want to allow a "less secure" application to send mail with your account:

[image: gmail turns on less secure apps for email]

There is an annoyance of getting too much mail. For example every time you mistype your `sudo` password you will get an email: [Stop emailing me bad sudo password attempts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986696/stop-emailing-me-bad-sudo-password-attempts)