# ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587

Tags: 14.04, email, gmail, ssmtp

I try to send a email using ssmtp but it not working

**My ssmtp config file**

```
root=test@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
AuthUser=test@gmail.com
AuthPass=*****
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTCTLS=YES
rewriteDomain=gmail.com
hostname=localhost
FromLineOverride=YES
TLS_CA_File=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

**revaliases**

```
root:test@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few small typos in your config. You have written:

```
UseSTARTCTLS=YES
        ^
```

(I have marked the error) where you should have written:

```
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

And finally the path for the certificates in Trusty should be written not as this:

```
TLS_CA_File=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

but more correctly as:

```
TLS_CA_File=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

These corrections should be enough to get you going :)

**References:**

- [Arch Wiki: SSMTP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=SSMTP)