# Stop emailing me bad sudo password attempts

Tags: 16.04, password, security, email

I have cron setup to backup every morning and email it to my gmail account and it works great. A nasty side-effect is whenever I type my password wrong using sudo I also get an email which is annoying:

[image: incorrect login]

I've googled a bit but can't find out how to turn off this email feature.

### Contents of `/etc/sudoers`

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Does your /etc/sudoers say `Defaults        mail_badpass` by any chance?

Comment: @steeldriver It's default file from clean install. I'll post contents into Q.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man sudoers`:

```
 mail_badpass      Send mail to the mailto user if the user running sudo
                   does not enter the correct password.  If the command
                   the user is attempting to run is not permitted by
                   sudoers and one of the mail_all_cmnds, mail_always,
                   mail_no_host, mail_no_perms or mail_no_user flags are
                   set, this flag will have no effect.  This flag is off
                   by default.
```

The flag is off by default - but enabled by Ubuntu's default /etc/sudoers file, as you have noted.

Presumably, you have started receiving these messages because `sudoers` default `mailto` is `root` - and you configured an MTA to deliver root's mail for `cron`. The messages should stop if you comment out the `Defaults    mail_badpass` line (using `sudo visudo`).

Comment: It is a bad idea to modify the default `/etc/sudoers`, as the changes may be lost after a package upgrade. Better create a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` with `Defaults !mail_badpass`.

Comment: `echo 'Defaults !mail_badpass' | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/disable_mail_badpass`