# How do I set Cron to send emails?

Tags: command-line, cron, email, rm

I have the following cron job command running once daily on my NAS device:

```
find /nfs/rpiggott/complete -mtime +45 -exec rm {} \;
```

I am wondering if there is a way to pipe a list that will result in the cron sending an e-mail to me showing what file it delete and / or any errors experienced.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this purposes you system should be able to send emails. So you could **install and configure `postfix`**:

```
sudo apt install postfix
```

- For *General type of mail configuration* choose ***Internet Site***, if you want to do more detailed configuration use the command:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
  ```

**At this stage Cron will start to send emails.** Everything that usually will be outputted to the STDOUT (if you are execute a command in the command line), including all error messages, will be sent to the local mailbox of the user that runs the Cronjob.

The default location of local user's mail boxes is `/var/mail/`. You can install the command-line email client `mutt` to read your user's email box via the command line in a convenient way:

```
sudo apt install mutt
```

- Note `mutt` installation process will involve installation and configuration of `postfix` if it isn't done before.

**You can change the default destination mailbox** by changing the value of the envvar `MAILTO` within `crontab`, before the definition of the Cronjob.

Please note: unless you haven't enabled SSL/TLS certificate within you send mail configuration, most of the public mail servers will ignore your emails in some way. For example `mail.google.com` will put them into the spam. If this is a server instance and you already have SSL/TLS certificate for your primary domain follow [this nice manual](https://www.upcloud.com/support/secure-postfix-using-lets-encrypt/) to attach it to Postfix.

Once your system is able to send emails you must **make your Cronjob more verbose** (for e.g. add `-v` to the `rm` command) and must set proper value of `MAILTO`. So your `crontab` should look as this:

```
MAILTO="example.email@gmail.com"
* * * * * find /nfs/rpiggott/complete -mtime +45 -exec rm -v {} \;
```

---

Another approach is to create a script (which will be executed via `crontab`) that includes your command and uses `mail`, `mutt`, `ssmtp` or `sendmail` to send emails. See the bottom of the references for mor details.

---

References and further reading:

- [Issues getting crontab to work](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018301/566421)
- [How To Install and Configure Postfix on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Postfix TLS Support](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html)
- [How to send mail from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/12917/566421)
- [5 Ways to Send Email From Linux Command Line](https://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/)

Comment: Recent vesions of `find` also recognize the `+` sign instead of `\;`, i.e. `find … -exec rm -v {} +` (instead of `find … -exec rm -v {} \;`. Depending on the number of files this will _greatly_ improve performance: with `\;` the `rm` command is run once per file (i.e. 1000 times for 1000 files) whereas the `+` variant will run `rm` with as many filenames as parameter as fit into the command line (i.e. it will call `rm` only twice or so, once with 800 files and a second time with 200 files).

Comment: (continued) A drawback might be unspecific error messages like `rm [800 filenames]: failed` whereas the `\;` would help to better identify the error because just a single filename is given.

Comment: I just tested the difference between the outputs  when `\;` or  `+` is engaged while `-exec rm -v {}` is used, the output is identical so probably `+` is a better choice. @PerlDuck

Comment: I think the real difference comes when there are errors. However, if you (or the OP) has only a few files to process (<100), then there's no significant difference, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

I used a pretty simple method to get `cron` to send emails: [Backup Linux configuration, scripts and documents to Gmail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917562/backup-linux-configuration-scripts-and-documents-to-gmail/922493#922493).

### Simplest way to automate sending email

From [Send email alerts using ssmtp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EmailAlerts) we find the simplest way of sending email automated from terminal or script. The installation steps are straight forward:

```
sudo apt install ssmtp
sudo nano /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
# Change "MyEmailAddress" and "MyPassword" to your own.
```

There  is one step not mentioned; Google will send you an email confirming you want to allow a "less secure" application to send mail with your account:

[image: gmail turns on less secure apps for email]

There is an annoyance of getting too much mail. For example every time you mistype your `sudo` password you will get an email: [Stop emailing me bad sudo password attempts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986696/stop-emailing-me-bad-sudo-password-attempts)

Comment: Instead of enabling `Allow less secure apps` you could instead `Create an App Password` and use that password in `ssmtp` instead of your own: Google will accept the email, not send to Spam, and as an added bonus you get the benefit of not keeping your real gmail password in your PC

Comment: @MestreLion I love that idea! Would you have a link to a good tutorial?

Comment: The official google documentation on App Passwords is by itself a pretty decent tutorial: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en