# How to Build report from mysqlcheck output

Tags: bash, mysql, text-processing, output

I need to build a report from the output of MySQL database check and auto-repair.
But dont want the full report each time : only in case of repair was needed

A scheduled (cron) a task runs mysqlcheck
I want to get informed  by email of eventual repair needed, repair success, repair fails...
But dont want the full report each time : only repairs

I run the mysqlcheck like this:

```
mysqlcheck --user=myuser --password=mypwd -c --auto-repair dbname > ouput.log
```

Found on a blog that the mysqlcheck output may looks like this in case of repair

```
Repairing tables
dbname.table1
warning  : Number of rows changed from 3 to 1
status   : OK
dbname.table2
warning  : Number of rows changed from 5454 to 5455
status   : OK
dbname.table3
warning  : Number of rows changed from 471859 to 471860
status   : OK
```

Since i cant find any official documentation about how looks the exact output,
I need help to build a report text file made by processing the output of mysqlcheck.
Perhaps some regex magician can make a report giving repaired tables names, faillure notice and so.

This refers to the mysql server available on official Ubuntu repositories
`mysql-server 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2`

Comment: i also found a blog that the output, it appears if you get `error: Table './yourDatabase/DatabaseLog' is marked as crashed and should be repaired!` when your program webpage trying to look for program data on mysql. that command should be auto repair your tables.

Comment: @abu-ahmed al-khatiri yep i have seen this too. I am looking for some official information reference to be sure that the script will have true reactions

Comment: are you get the same errors?

Comment: did you try with `-r` option?

Answer (score 2):

This simple script is getting the **mysqlcheck** result and checking the output for **"Repairing Tables"**. As this string only comes when the table is damaged.

If exist then it sends an email to the desired address.

```
#!/bin/bash

result=`mysqlcheck --user=myuser --password=mypass --auto-repair dbname;`

if [[ $result == *"Repairing tables"* ]]; then

  echo $result | mailx -s 'email subject'  username@example.com

fi
```

Comment: Hi @Mohit Malviya. Did you find some information reference about the output of mysqlcheck ?

Comment: Yes, I successfully simulate the environment. I manually damage a table and then try to repair it using mysqlcheck. You also can have a look at https://pastebin.com/2Lsbn5Mz

Comment: 1. How did you damage a table ? - 2. regarding to  your paste, did the repair be successfull ? 3. Many thanks

Comment: 1. I manually edit the file "ad_overlay_codes.frm" Which is present in "/var/lib/mysql". 2. While i edit the file manualluy and delete some data of it, The repair is unsuccessful. 3. Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

### `--silent` mode

When running `mysqlcheck` pass the parameter `-s` or `--silent` and [only error messages will print](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html#option_mysqlcheck_silent).

Modify your command like this:

```
mysqlcheck --user=myuser --password=mypwd -c --auto-repair --silent dbname
```

No need to redirect output to a working file and parse it. You do need `cron` setup to send emails. From this Q&A: [How do I set Cron to send emails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020965/how-do-i-set-cron-to-send-emails)

```
MAILTO="example.email@gmail.com"
* * * * * mysqlcheck --user=myuser --password=mypwd -c --auto-repair --silent dbname
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best thing would be to set it up this way:

- in `crontab -e` schedule a bashscript e.g:

```
 - * * * * /bin/bash /root/custom-mysqlrepair.sh
```

- create such script with something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#hint: adding user and password to .my.cnf should remove the need for user and password in this command
OUTPUT=$((mysqlcheck --user=myuser --password=mypwd -c --auto-repair dbname) 2>&1)
OUTPUT_NO_NEWLINES=`$OUTPUT | tr '\n'`
if [[ $string == *"Number of rows changed from"* ]]; then
  echo $OUTPUT
fi
```

- make the script executable and place it in /root/

now what's going to happen:

- cron runs script
- script tries to run your command and saves output to variable
- IF the variable contains your desired word, print whole output
- crontab should catch output into MAILTO output and email it normally

Please note this is still untested theory, but should get you going.

Comment: there's no need for email component. crontabs have build-in MAILTO variable to send the emails to. since OP already stated he uses crontab, he may as well use that which I believe he already did.

Comment: Since you choose to make crond send email, he will do it. But i only want a report in case of repair