# Crontab is not emailing me errors

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, email

I have a script called `cron-test.sh` with a line of code to trigger an error:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Cron Tab is Running"
asdfadsf
```

My `crontab -e` has this:

```
* * * * * /home/user/cron-test.sh
```

I can't seem to get any emails of the error in my script, I know email configuration is set up properly because I tested the following in `crontab -e` and I get emails every minute telling me "Cron Tab is Running".

```
MAILTO="me@email.com"
* * * * * /home/user/cron-test.sh
```

How do I receive an email when an error occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make crontab email me with output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536766/how-to-make-crontab-email-me-with-output)

Comment: Are you asking why your `MAILTO` environment variable needs to be set explicitly in the crontab, rather than being inherited from somewhere?

Comment: My understanding is that crontab by default will automatically email me when there's an error with the script it runs. When I have "asdfadsf" in my script, that throws an error. However, crontab is not emailing me that this script threw an error.

Comment: Without a `MAILTO` variable, AFAIK it will attempt to mail to the crontab's owner *locally*, using something equivalent to `user@localhost.localdomain`. The mail should end up in `/var/mail/user` (although for that to work, you need a full mail server running on the localhost I think - rather than a mail forwarder such as `ssmtp` or the like).

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver